# echo $PATH does not reflect the "export PATH" I made in shell script

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, path

I have created a shell script that will check if a certain value is existing in `PATH`. If not, then it will add that value to the `PATH` environment variable.

It was successfully added, based on the `echo $PATH` run inside the shell script. But when I tried to run `echo $PATH` in command line.. it does not reflect the changes made.

Here is my code:

```
#!/bin/bash
postgresPath="/opt/PostgreSQL/9.2/bin"
echo "Checking PATH env.."
[[ ":$PATH:" != *"$postgresPath"* ]] && export PATH="${PATH}:$postgresPath"
echo $PATH
```

http://rextester.com/RBLTT17164

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/53177/bash-script-to-set-environment-variables-not-working

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The script runs in its own environment.  It can not affect the environment of its parent shell (from which you start the script), i.e. changing `$PATH` in a script won't change `$PATH` in your interactive shell.

A mini-example of this:

```
$ echo "$PATH"
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/X11R6/bin:/usr/local/bin

$ ( PATH="hello"; echo "$PATH" )
hello

$ echo "$PATH"
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/X11R6/bin:/usr/local/bin
```

(it does not matter if I `export` the `PATH` variable again in the subshell since it's already exported)

I suggest either sourcing the script with `.` or `source`, which would execute the commands therein in the same environment as the current shell, or turning the script into a shell function.

Comment: ok thanks, I get it now.. but still, my shell script will recognize the modified env PATH, right? only inside the script..

Comment: @john1717 Yes. The script itself will execute with the modified `$PATH`, and any processes it start will have the modified `$PATH`, but it won't be propagated back to the parent shell.

Answer (score 0):

To Overcome the issue, I have added this into my

```
~/.bash_aliases
```

The below line and tested, working as expected.

```
function ep () { [ -n "$1" ] && DIR=$(readlink -fq $1) || DIR=$PWD; echo -e "exporting PATH (\e[33m$DIR\e[m)"; PATH=$DIR:$PATH; }
```

Usage:

```
bashSHELL$ ep
or
bashSHELL$ ep /path/to/dir
or
bashSHELL$ ep ../path/to/dir
etc.
```

Comment: After adding the line, we need to start a new bash or restart the terminal.